# How to clear server or network share connection history in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: nautilus, 13.04, connection

How can I delete connection URLs present in File > Connect To Server

For security reasons I want to remove all these connection URLs to which I have connected.

Answer (score 20):

The history is stored in either `~/.config/nautilus/servers` or `~/.cache/nautilus/servers`. If you rename or delete this file your recent 'connect to server' locations will be cleared.

Comment: Thanks! This also works for ubuntu 16.04-tls

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 22.04, it is saved as XML file in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/servers`. You can just delete this file to remove the history.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the below steps to clear used server address history**

**1**.Go to home folder and press Cnt+H(Used to hide or show the folders and files)

**2**.Go to .config folder

**3**.And Go to Nautilus folder

**4**.And delete the file with the name as Servers(XML-Format File)